# Using part of another project in my project

Tags: licensing

I want to use a couple of image files from Chromium project in my project. The Chromium license says that "Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice...".

Where should I put that copyright notice?

http://code.google.com/chromium/terms.html

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a LICENSE file where you state, that the images are licensed under the BSD license and that the original copyright belongs to the chromium authors.

Comment: I searched stackoverflow for this - you will find additional information by doing so - if needed ;) Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/462302/bsd-license-reference-to-other-software

Comment: But I have my own license (MIT) in the LICENSE file.

Comment: You only state that the part taken from chrome is licensed under BSD. You can license your code freely.